# Having trouble getting url query parameter in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am just trying to get the value of a parameter in my url.

I'm new to next.js and still fairly new to react in general.

My url looks like:

```
localhost:3000/?code=VhXHWwRemC32dPmm3oj0mMravO6MP3
```

Right now, I just am rendering a page like:

```
const Index = () => {
       const router = useRouter();
       const code = router.query.code;
       console.log(code);
       return(
       <div>
           <p>code: {code}</p>
           <a href={Oauth.discord_login_url}login</a>
           </div>)
        };
```

Just so I can see if I'm getting the code correctly from the url.

Once I log in with discord, I return to Index and the url then looks like what I showed above. I am trying to get the value of code so I can use it. What confuses me is that

```
<p>code: {code}</p>
```

successfully displays the value of "code" on the page. But

```
console.log(code)
```

shows undefined. Why is it different?

Comment: Does it still returns undefined if you try `console.log("code: "+ code);`?

Comment: Yes. It says "code: undefined".

Comment: And `console.log(router.query)`? Also, show a screen shot how the view looks. Thats actually strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add `getInitialProps`:

```
const Index = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const code = router.query.code;
  console.log(code); 

  Index.getInitialProps = async () => {
    return {};
  };

 return ( 
   <div>
     <p>code: {code}</p> 
     <a href={Oauth.discord_login_url}>login</a>
   </div>
  ) 

};
```

Comment: Oh dang. That seems to have fixed my issue. Thank you!