# Why my search result page can fetch the input words?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

I'm writing the search result page now and I want to use dynamic route to implement. This is my search bar code,

```
<Link href={`/productSearchResult/${searchWord}`}>
  <a className={styles.navbar_searchbar_dataResult_productItem}>
    <p>{filteredData}</p>
  </a>
</Link>
```

`searchWord` is the user's input, and if user click the autocompleted link, it will jump into the `searchResult` page.
This is my search result code,

```
import Navbar from "../../components/navbar"
import Head from "next/dist/shared/lib/head"
import searchResult from "../../components/searchResult"
import productList from "../../components/productList"

export default function productionSearchResult({ searchName }) {

  const [searchedProducts, setSearchedProducts] = useState([])
  console.log(searchName);
  const productsInformation = searchResult(searchName);
  productsInformation.then(function(result) {
    setSearchedProducts(result.props)
  })
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Growcery | Search Result</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Your search result | Growcery" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Navbar/>
      <main>
        <p>Showing results for {searchName}</p>
        <productList products={searchedProducts} />
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ product_name }) {
  const productName = product_name;
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK}search-products/${productName}/`);
  let data = "";
  if (res)
    data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      products: data.data || "",
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote a `console.log(searchName)` to see if the code can fetch the `searchName`, here is the screenshot of my google Chrome.
[route path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJNp5.png)
[console.log(searchName) in google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krsyi.png)

But I can only see `undefined` in my chrome terminal.

Comment: Your `productionSearchResult` component expects a `searchName` prop but the `getServerSideProps` function only returns `products`. Where is `searchName` meant to come from? Also, you should move all async operations in your component inside a `useEffect` instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is an easy way catch query parameter and use it any where in
   component.
2. It also depend on your routing for this your route must
   be like.

```
       <Route exact path="/productSearchResult/:name?"></Route>
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
      import Navbar from "../../components/navbar"
    import Head from "next/dist/shared/lib/head"
    import searchResult from "../../components/searchResult"
    import productList from "../../components/productList"
    
    export default function productionSearchResult({props}) {
    
      const [searchedProducts, setSearchedProducts] = useState([])
       let searchName = props.match.params.name;
      console.log(searchName);
      const productsInformation = searchResult(searchName);
      productsInformation.then(function(result) {
        setSearchedProducts(result.props)
      })
      
      return (
        <div>
          <Head>
            <title>Growcery | Search Result</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Your search result | Growcery" />
            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
          </Head>
          <Navbar/>
          <main>
            <p>Showing results for {searchName}</p>
            <productList products={searchedProducts} />
          </main>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export async function getServerSideProps({ product_name }) {
      const productName = product_name;
      const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK}search-products/${productName}/`);
      let data = "";
      if (res)
        data = await res.json();
    
      return {
        props: {
          products: data.data || "",
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Next.js has its own [built-in router](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction), it doesn't use React Router.

Comment: for next.js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130235/having-trouble-getting-url-query-parameter-in-next-js